# Mongoose createConnection returns undefined when it is inside Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, jestjs

I am using Jest for testing my app developed in Typescript.

I have a class that creates a connection in its costructor.
I need it in the constructor so that I can export the class with no problem.

`mongoose.createConnection` does not return a Promise. So I think it is a good way of doing it.

```typescript
//myconnection.ts

import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export class MyConnection{

  this.mongoose_options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
  }

  constructor(uri){
    this.connection = mongoose.createConnection(uri, this.mongoose_options);
    this.connection.on('connected', () => {
      console.log('CONNECTED');
    })
  }

}
```

When I try to test this class in Jest I get `undefined` instead of a `mongoose.Connection`

```typescript
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {MyConnection} from './myconnection';

it('should call mongoose.createConnection', () => {

  const spy = jest.spyOn(mongoose, 'createConnection');
  const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db';
  const mycon = new MyConnection(uri);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

When I run jest the constructor throw an error saying that `this.connection` is undefined

```
Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Everything works perfectly outside jest. 
The function returns a `mongoose.Conncetion` and I can set all the events on it.

Why do I get `undefined` when I am inside Jest? From the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-createConnection)  there is no mention of `undefined` as a possible return value.

**EDIT**

I am trying also by simply connecting mongoose without importing my class

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

it('should call mongoose.createConnection', async () => {

  const spy = jest.spyOn(mongoose, 'createConnection');
  const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db';
  const mycon = await mongoose.connect(uri);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

I still get `undefined`.

Is this the right way of testing? What am I missing?

Comment: I think spy is for methods. Functions exported by a module and referenced through a `* as m` are not methods of `m`

Comment: Thank you but even without doing anything in my test function, I always get `undefined` as a result from `mongoose.connect` or `mongoose.createConnection`

Comment: That is indeed strange. What if you just create a JS file that does nothing aside from import `mongoose` and call `createConnection` and then run this file directly with node?

Comment: I added `globals.ts-jest.tsConfig = 'tsconfig.js'` to my `jest.config.js` and now it loads it. Thanks for the help.